# Why aren't all c++ libaries included automatically upon start up?

Tags: c++

So yeah, questions in the title. But the reason why am asking is because am taking video tutorials at The New Boston (which is awesome by the way) and I was wondering; Why do we have to import the libraries ourselves? and I don't mean every lib in c++ created by every programmer, but the most commonly used ones, like cstdlib, or cmath?

Comment: Why bothering the compiler with parsing and compiling something that you might not need?

Comment: What do you mean by "import the libraries"? The standard C and C++ libraries are *linked* to the programs by default.

Comment: the **simplified** answer is, that the compiler would have to read all the standard .h's for every one of your .c's which would be slow.

Comment: If they're not used, there's no point in building them into your executable. Not every program will need to make use of cmath, or output to a stream etc.

Comment: Do you always need all 'common' libraries? I don't think so. Including libraries makes your program bigger and slower.

Comment: Because we dont even need most of them!

Comment: Why to waste unnecessary time in compiling codes which aren't required ,which could be in fact a much longer when boost libraries comes into picture

Comment: You could create your own include file (e.g. `tutorial.h`) in which you `#include` all the libraries that are used throughout the tutorials

Comment: @szx Please don't give unnecessary and poor advices to beginners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different things involved here. When you build your application, the build system links to the standard library, and the linker pulls in whatever code is needed from that library, as well as any others that you may have specified.

What you're talking about here is **not** libraries, but **headers**. Headers describe the contents of source files, so that you can compile a source file and refer to things that are defined somewhere else. For example,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    puts("Hello, world");
    return 0;
}
```

The header `<stdio.h>` tells the compiler that there's a function named `puts` that can be called with a string literal (`"Hello, world\n"`) as its argument. This function is defined in the standard library, so linking to the standard library gets you the code that makes this work.

Unlike Java, the designers of C++ decided that the compiler should not paw through your hard drive to try to figure out what things you want to use in your code. You have to tell it, and headers are the mechanism for doing that. Using more headers than you need means processing more text than you need, and that, in turn, means slower compilation.

Comment: Ahhh, so particular libs have particular headings and one of those libs is a header called <head name> that gives you (function). 

So, a compiler is like a catalogue I guess. It has to go to <header>, go back to the, lets say, the initialization path, and then go grab another header from that start point?

If I may ask another question, is a lib just a collection of headers? If so, how do you know what library to use/how to call it. 

Many thanks

-James.

Comment: A header is a text file. When the compiler sees `#include whatever` it reads the text from that file as if it had been part of the file that it's compiling. Nothing more. At this point I suggest you ignore the details of headers and libraries. Later on you'll start writing programs that consist of more than one source file, and you'll learn all about headers and linking when you do that.

Comment: Sweet, cheers man, thanks for the help.

It's hard to start of programming (as am sure you know) so it's good there's people on this site like yourself to offer some guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Including libraries has cost.  Their symbols make compilation take longer and they make the resulting executable larger.  Names in some libraries can conflict with names in others, or with names in your own code.  If the are 'imported' automatically, then how would you 'unimport' them?  Who decides what is "commonly used"?  I rarely ever use stdlib in C++ projects.  I use math sometimes, but not often.

I can't think of a language with "packages" that imports any by default.  (Java, C#, python, C/C++)

Comment: `java.lang` is auto-imported, no? So is the contents of `exceptions` in Python2, but in Python3 they're just builtins.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why even standard C++ library headers aren't automatically included is because that would (at very least) significantly increase compilation times. See, inclusion of a header file is simply pasting its contents at the site of the `#include` statement, so you might end with a very long translation unit, even though you do not actually need the included code.

Answer (score 0):

The question is that if you include everything, the compiler will take a much longer time to parse and compile your projects. It is a pain in the ass sometimes especially when it comes to
mpl(meta template program) since the stl is mostly written in templates.

But you can take the most common libs into consideration and import them everytime you set up a new project.

Answer (score 0):

"Import" is not the right term.  Those libraries, no header files for the libraries, are "include"d.  The `#include` files inform the compiler about the signature of different functions and other useful definitions.  If you include everything under the Sun automatically, that will increase the compiler's work and lead to longer compilation time.  It will also make the compiler need more memory.  An additional benefit is that the compiler *knows* the programmer's intentions when appropriate headers are provided.

C/C++ aim at keeping the code tight, with a smaller code footprint.  They want to keep the use of memory as the most efficient possible, and that philosophy is reflected in the compiler as well.